# Elmish.WPF type conflict: unit -> Model expected where Model provided?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

My [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF) app combines the [Elmish.WPF Sample](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples) projects [‘NewWindow’](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow) + [‘NewWindow.Core’](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core) which I am adding to a copy of [‘FileDialogsCmdMsg’](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/FileDialogs) + [‘FileDialogsCmdMsg.Core’](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/FileDialogs.Core).

`FileDialogsCmdMsg` is the basis of this effort and provides the background processing features to which I am adding the ‘NewWindow’ popup window features.

I am stuck on two (2) type-conflicts when `WpfProgram.mkProgramWithCmdMsg` is called...

[image: wpfprogram-called-showing-errors]

...errors on `update` and `bindings` calls.

The compiler reports that line has the following errors (see red underlines above)...

[image: type-error-messages]

...saying that `WpfProgram.mkProgramWithCmdMsg` expects a `unit -> Model` but was given a `Model` where `update` and `bindings` are called in the larger type specification.

But here is the type information for the calling function,  `WpfProgram.mkProgramWithCmdMsg` accepting these parameters…

[image: wpfprogram-extected-type-information]

... *sorry that is so large.*

As you can see, both ‘update’ and ‘bindings’ are producing the `Model` parameter types expected by `WpfProgram.mdProgramWithCmdMsg`. **And yet we have a `unit->Model` expected where a `Model` has been provided type-conflict; why?**

Here is more detail on the `update` type-conflict…

[image: update-type-conflict]

... see how here how here it is claimed a `unit->Model` is expected when previously you see that `update` is supposed to expect a `Model`?  *Why?*

You see the same problem in this detail on the type-conflict with ‘bindings’...

[image: bindings-type-conflict]

..again showing `unit-Model' expected when the correct` Model` type parameter is passed.

Here the type information where `update` is defined…

[image: update-type-information]

...and here is the `bindings` type info…

[image: bindings-type-information]

**QUESTION: Why is a "`unit->Model` expected error reported when the receiving function, `WpfProgram.mkProgramWithCmdMsg`, and both parameters, `update` and `bindings` both respectively provide `Model` parameters?**

Please ask if more detail is needed to get to the bottom of this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When working with Elmish.WPF and Bolero, I always nail down the signature of certain functions in order to avoid the chaos we see here. In that way I will not be lead astray when the type inference results in highly confusing and misleading information being given by the compiler. I suggest you explicitly declare types for arguments and return values of the functions init, update and bindings. Following that the compiler should be able to give you better advice.

Comment: You know, I suspected that was good practice but now I'll make that one the first tools when tackling this kind of mystery; thank you.  BTW, @BentTranberg, another newbie Q why do you prefer Bolero over Fable or Giraffe?  - RCHF

Comment: Several historical and technical reasons, but it all boils down to Bolero being the easy alternative. I am not primarily a web developer, I work solo on a gargantuan project, and I can't cope with it all without simplicity. Same reasons I use F# and not C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your `init` function, which (I'm guessing) is a function of type `unit -> Model`. If this is true, the lambda `fun _ -> init, []` binds the concrete type `unit -> Model` to the `'model` type variable. As result, `update` and `bindings` also expect the same concrete type, leading to the error message you're seeing.

If I'm correct, you have two choices:

- Change `init` so it is a value of type `Model`, rather than a function.
- Change `init` so it also returns an empty message list, and then pass `init` directly to `mkProgramWithCmdMsg`, rather than passing a lambda.

Note that when you hover over `mkProgramWithCmdMsg`, the compiler shows you that `'model` is indeed bound to `unit -> Model`, presumably due to the `init` type mismatch:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Brian.  That was it.  I totally missed the implications of my mis-definition of `init()`

My solution now compiles and runs.